# i have encountered error while trying to run a JSP file in my web browser

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I tried to run my web project in a web browser. while running one of the JSP file I encountered following Unable to compile class for JSP:

[image: screenshot of internal server error]

Comment: Could you copy the text in your error and paste it into a code block, rather than paste an image?

Answer (score 0):

First let me remark, that using scriptlets `<% ... %>` in JSP pages is deprecated since about 20 years (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/11748454) on how to replace them).

In your JSP page you are using [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html), which is part of JAXB. JAXB was removed from Java SE 9 and later versions. However since Java SE 8 you can use [`Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) to encode a byte array using Base 64.

Therefore replace:

```
<%@page import="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter"%>
...
String b64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
```

with

```
<%@page import="java.util.Base64"%>
...
String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageInByteArray);
```

Comment: i replaced this code   <%@page import="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter"%>
...
" String b64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);   with the code you wrote above but after running it in the server it showed same error ,upon checking the jsp.java file . i saw  string b64=DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray); reappear again

Comment: Did you replace it in `stationview.jsp` or `stationview_jsp.java`? The latter is generated by Tomcat and regularly overwritten.